# How do I insert a value into a column of an existing row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table in oracle with existing values as given.
Now what I want is, to insert value in the '**logout_time**' field in that same table with a where clause checking for the **Username** present in that same table.

**User_login table:**
**USERNAME   LOGIN_DAY   LOGIN_TIME   LOGOUT_TIME** 
admin             24-MAR-16       16:27:38

I have attempted the following query statement. But its throwing error as '**SQL command not properly ended**'.

```
insert into user_login(logout_time) values ('17:12:40') where username='admin'
```

What is the solution for this?

P.S: This is not a duplicate question. I have checked all the questions relating to this, present here.But found no solution.

Can someone please help me out ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: UPDATE user_login set logout_time=  '17:12:40' where username='admin' ?

Comment: Do you need to insert a new record or update a field of an existing record?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I needed to update. I guess i could not frame my question well. It worked. I forgot about the update part :|

Answer (score 1):

You need to `UPDATE` the table, not `INSERT` into it, do this:

```
update table user_login 
set logout_time ='17:12:40'
where username='admin'
```